# Flipping 3D cube in CSS, transition height after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do a simple 2 sided cube rotation. After the rotation I want to click one of the sides and make the height increase, however the transition takes place from the middle, not top down (like height transition does normally) so I tried changing the transform-origin.

The other issue  is, if I change this to 90deg, on mouse move, it triggers mouseleave and fluctuates between the two states, click event doesn't work properly then either.

```
.cube.active {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
   transform: rotateX(89deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7y4N/27/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe it is better to remove the limitation of transition to transform:

just do:

```
-webkit-transition: .33s;
    transition: .33s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7y4N/30/

also you have two different transition times. one for the container of .33s and one for the height of the inner with 1s. so the outer is finished its height-transition and the inner is not finished and take place in the middle.

Comment: Thanks but it seems to have the same effect?

Comment: Thanks, i dont understand why giving the parent transition property worked?

Comment: i changed my answer above to explain it.